# Django - NoReverseMatch after simple changes in code

Tags: python, html, django

So,long story short,I started learning Django basics this week and followed a simple poll creating tutorial,which worked fine,but then I started trying to make a few changes to the code,and due to my inexperience in Django(and to be honest,also in HTML),I ended up getting this NoReverseMatch error. What I basically did was try to change the name of a class and it's uses in the app,and it's objects along the project(class TText).
Then the errors started showing up at both the /polls/* ( * being respective id number for a TText) and /polls/*/results in the localhost web page.
The first one gives the following error at `detail.html`,line 5:

```
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<text_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$']
```

And the second at `results.html`,line 9:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

And here's my setup of this django app:

```
/mysite
    urls.py
/polls
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    /templates
        /polls
            detail.html
            index.html
            results.html
```

Where: `/mysite/urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

also -  `/polls/models.py` :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class TText(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    text = models.ForeignKey(TText, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

also - `/polls/urls.py` :

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<text_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

also - `/polls/views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, TText


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_text_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return TText.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = TText
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = TText
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, text_id):
    text = get_object_or_404(TText, pk=text_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = text.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'text': text,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(text.id,)))
```

also - `/polls/templates/polls/detail.html`:

```
<h1>{{ text.text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' text.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in text.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

also: `/polls/templates/polls/index.html` :

```
{% if latest_text_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for text in latest_text_list %}
       <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' text.id %}">{{ text.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

also - `/polls/templates/polls/results.html` :

```
<h1>{{ text.text}}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in text.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' text.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

PS: It's the first time a post a question here on Stack,so feel free to point out any mistake on that as well.
OH,and yes, I did read the other posts of similar problems,but I coudn't match any of them with my own problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: On which page to you get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context passed into generic views is based on the `Model` name. You have two options in the template, you can use either `object` or `name_of_model`. In your case, that's `ttext`. Alternatively, you can tell the generic view what to call the object in the context:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = TText
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'text'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = TText
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    context_object_name = 'text'
```

Then you can use what you're currently doing in your templates: `text.id` instead of `ttext.id` or `object.id`.

Comment: Well thank you!! It's beautifully working again thanks to that small change. And your explanation helped me figure what I did wrong as well!

Answer (score 0):

The problems are in your URL template tags. Essentially you are telling Django to find a URL that doesn't exist.

The main issue as far as I can see is that you are referring to a template variable `text` which doesn't exist. It doesn't exist because those templates are being rendered by Django's generic views, and the generic views use `object` as their standard template variable name for a single object. If you just change `text` to `object` in those template files you should get a better result.

The other option is to declare a context object name on the view class, like you've done in `IndexView` - `context_object_name = 'latest_text_list'`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,it really helped me understanding the concept behind my mistake!